# check if two address "might" be the same in php

Tags: php, regex

I have this address:

```
Grimshaw Lane, Bollington, Macclesfield SK10 5JB,
```

Looking for this address, I obtain this (from an API):

```
Bollington Wharf, Grimshaw Lane, Bollington, United Kingdom
```

I know how work preg_match, but I believe there's must be anyway to compare two similars texts (similar, not the same), and decide if they are the same address (even if they are a little differents).

Comment: Good question. But a solution is far more complex than a string/preg_match comparison.

Comment: To figure out if they are the same address, use Google Maps.

Comment: Have you checked out [similar_text()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)?

Comment: the problem is that this process could be a little slow....making more requests..., but it's a good idea, very creative.

Comment: if you need to research this more, the term you need to search for is "geocoding".

Comment: what's the api you're using?

Comment: ey, sorry, I'm using google places

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's obviously no solution that's going to get you 100% reliable results, but why not try this: Send both strings to Google Maps via wget and compare the results. Google has invested, at the least, tens of thousands of man-hours into solving the problem that you're looking at, why not just let them deal with it?

Comment: The only workable way. There is no way to do this by looking at the strings.

Comment: ok...It's a solution. Thanks a lot. I'm going to wait for more ideas, but it's a solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is indeed likely to be the most reliable answer, probably by some margin. String searching on its own is never going to give you anything approaching an acceptable level of accuracy, unless you've got a database the size of Google's behind it. The only problem with this answer is if you need to process a lot of data; Google has limits to the number of queries you can make to their APIs. If you need more than that limit, it can get expensive.

Comment: I agree, geocoding is the only way you are going to get to a somewhat accurate system. String comparison is very error prone (St. Street, Saint, ST)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this helps, but I would consider using a combination of using explode to create multiple strings in an array an levenshtein() to compare the different elements of the array().

It depends on how many arrays you would have to compare, but if you just have a few (NOT thousands)

Psudo code would be something like this:

```
$search_address = "Bollington Wharf, Grimshaw Lane, Bollington, United Kingdom";

$my_addresses = Array("Grimshaw Lane, Bollington, Macclesfield SK10 5JB", 
                         "Different Lane, YabbaDabbaDoo, Otherfield SK12 6BJ", 
                         ...);
$search_array = explode(',', $search_address);

$best_address = array();
$lowest_compare_value = 1000;
$lowest_compare_address = array();
foreach($my_addresses as $key => $my_address) {
   $current_address_array = explode(',', $value);
   $compare_value = 0;

   foreach(<elements in $my_address>) {

      $lowest_value = 1000;      
      foreach(<elements in $search_array) {
          $new_value = levenshtein($search_element, $my_element);
          if ($new_value < $lowest_value) { $lowest_value = $new_value; }
      }
      $compare_value += $lowest_value;
   }
   if($compare_value < $lowest_compare_value) {
      $lowest_compare_value = $compare_value
      $lowest_compare_address = $my_address;
   }

}
```

Now you should also consider what maximum plausible levenshtein value could be to check if compared address is too far off.

As mentioned this method takes time and should NOT be used in an application that needs a lot of speed or if you have many local addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I created this utility and it has been working for me for a while. Of course if Google maps changes their API interface it will have to be modified.

```
<?php
// Queries google maps for the address components
function utl_GetAddressComponents( $location )
{
    $components = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($location).'&sensor=false');
    $output = json_decode($components);

    return $output->results[0];
}
?>
```

Here is a test file I used to run it from a command line:

```
tst_MatchingAddresses.php:

<?php
require_once( "utl_GetAddressComponents.php" );
$addr1 = $argv[1];
$addr2 = $argv[2];

$gmapsResult1 = utl_GetAddressComponents( $addr1 );
$gmapsResult2 = utl_GetAddressComponents( $addr2 );

$gmapsAddr1 = $gmapsResult1->formatted_address;
$gmapsAddr2 = $gmapsResult2->formatted_address;

print("Gmap1: ".$gmapsAddr1." ----- argv[1]: ".$argv[1]."\n");
print("Gmap2: ".$gmapsAddr2." ----- argv[2]: ".$argv[2]."\n");

if ( strcmp($gmapsAddr1,$gmapsAddr2) )
{
    print("==> Addresses match!\n");
}
else
{
    print("==> Addresses DO NOT MATCH!\n");
}
?>
```

Here is an example command line:

```
php tst_MatchingAddresses.php "1600 Pennsylvania Ave, Washington DC" "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, 20500"
```

Example output:

```
Gmap1: 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue Northwest, President's Park, Washington, DC 20500, USA ----- argv[1]: 1600 Pennsylvania Ave, Washington DC
Gmap2: 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue Northwest, President's Park, Washington, DC 20500, USA ----- argv[2]: 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, 20500
==> Addresses match!
```

Note: You can enter the argument to file_get_contents, replacing urlencode, etc. with an address, directly into a browser and it will display the json results.